# ATG dsp form input value

Tags: jquery, forms, jsp, atg

I am trying to get a form to submit without reloading the whole page.  I am very confident that I have the logic working for this as I am using an event listener to circumvent the default form submission logic.

```
$("body").on("click", '#buttonHolder', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#storeCart').serialize(),
            dataType: "html",
            url: "/inc/store/cart/cart-contents.jsp",
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) {
                $("#formHolder").html(response);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Where my dsp form looks like this

```
<dsp:form action="" id="storeCart" formid="storeCart" method="post">
  <dsp:droplet name="/atg/dynamo/droplet/IsEmpty">
      <dsp:param name="value" param="element.WarrantyId"/>
         <dsp:oparam name="true">
            <input type="text" value='<dsp:valueof param="element.quantity" />' maxlength="3" class="inputQuantity" name='<dsp:valueof param="element.catalogRefId"/>' id='quantity-<dsp:valueof param="element.catalogRefId"/>'/>
         </dsp:oparam>
      <dsp:oparam name="false">
         <dsp:valueof param="element.quantity" />
            <input type="hidden" value='<dsp:valueof param="element.quantity" />' maxlength="3" class="inputQuantity" name='<dsp:valueof param="element.catalogRefId"/>' id='quantity-<dsp:valueof param="element.catalogRefId"/>'/>
      </dsp:oparam>
    </dsp:droplet>
  <td id="buttonHolder"><dsp:input value="Submit" type="submit" bean="......"/></td>
</dps:form>
```

The problem is that it doesn't seem to want to change the values after I add them in on the front end.  To be more clear:

The input field is value 1.  If I go ahead and change it to 4, then inspect the element, the value is still 1, and this is reflected when the form submits and the response is generated.  So doing a console.log($('testID').val()); on the input gives me a 1, not a 4 (desired).  This is also going through in the request headers.

Edit:

I updated the dsp form section to more accurately reflect the fields with their shadow hidden fields.  I can't seem to get the form to accept new inputs.  The values assert themselves as the values stored in the jsp variables, even when injecting new values into the chrome inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Every input field has a corresponding hidden form element created by ATG internally by the DSP tag. Are you setting relevant hidden field (like below the firstname text field has a corresponding hidden field which starts with _D:/atg..etc.,)

The hidden value has to be set to what server is sending as you are not reloading the page as you update your text field.

```
<input id=“testid” class=“teststyle " type=“text” value="" name="/atg/something/SomeFormHandler.value.firstname” maxlength="60">
<input type="hidden" value=" " name="_D:/atg/something/SomeFormHandler.value.firstname>
```

Comment: Yes, I have the hidden fields there.  Is it not possible to change the value of this input pair from the chrome console?  I can't manage changing the variables unless I step back and do a normal form submission which will refresh the whole page (not desired)

Comment: If the page gets reloaded, the server is taking certain actions to populate the _D (Hidden fields) so that it knows what values changed on the server side and populates appropriate values in the background.

Comment: Check for DYN_SESSION_CONF if you are maintaining it so that the form is really getting submitted to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Your code above appears to be inconsistent in its usage of the the ATG dsp tags.

Try using the `<dsp:input>` tags instead of the html `<input>` tag.  This will ensure the fields are appropriately mapped to the ATG FormHandler when you submit the form e.g.

```
<dsp:input bean='YourFormHandler.value.quantity' name='<dsp:valueof param="element.catalogRefId"/>' id='quantity-<dsp:valueof param="element.catalogRefId"/>' type="hidden" iclass="inputQuantity" value='<dsp:valueof param="element.quantity" />' maxlength="3" />
```